# Am I referencing this array position wrong?

Tags: java

Hi I am writing a method for a larger program but I keep getting the error that symbol cannot be found. please help!

```
 public static int maxInc (char []ch)
 {
  int current = 1;
  int max = 1;

  if (ch.length == 0)
  {
     return 0;
  }
  else if (ch.length == 1)
  {
     return 1;
  }
  else
  {
     for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++);
     {
        if(ch[i] >= ch[i-1]) //the error is at ch[i] and ch[i-1]
        {
           current++;
           if(current > max)
              max = current;
           else 
              current = 1;   
        }
     } 
     return max;
  }         
   }
```

Comment: `keep getting the error that symbol cannot be found.` What, you don't think telling us the "undefined symbol" is useful information?

Comment: You should accept one answer which is worked for you by marking the mark beside the answer. Just visit our [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a semi colon in this line :

```
for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++);
```

Remove it and make the line as below:

```
for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++)
```

While there is a semicolon what is happening that the loop happen while nothing was done. It became just a statement. This below code was happening like second example:

**This Sample Code**

```
for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++);
{
     if(ch[i] >= ch[i-1])
      {
          current++;
          if(current > max)
              max = current;
          else 
              current = 1;   
       }
}
```

**Will work Like this**

```
for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++)
{
      //Nothing is happening
}

// i will give error as the declaration was in the above loop
if(ch[i] >= ch[i-1])
{
     current++;
     if(current > max)
        max = current;
      else 
        current = 1;   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++);
```

The problem is there, the semicolon. Remove it. This way, your for loop effectively looks like...

```
 for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++) { 
    // do nothing
}
```

"`For`" executes the next block, but you ended that block with a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line give error:

```
for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++);
```

Modify it as follow

```
for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++)
```

If not, tell me which line give you error.